# Load data into php page and bring back page via dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need some assistance with some code I'm sending over data via jQuery to a php page and trying to load the page using dialog from jQUeryUI. The page is loading on the modal but the data sent is not showing up on the modal box

here is jQuery code...

```
var info = {'production_line_number' : production_line_number,
            'report_date' :date, 'shift_number' : shift_number,
            'report_id' : report_id, 'username' : username};
var url = '/best/Pages/DailyShiftReport/PageSection/IrrecoverableFilmScrap.php';

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    cache: false,
    data:  {result: JSON.stringify(info)},
    url: url
}).done(function(){
    var my_dialog =  $('#test_dialog_org').load(url);
    my_dialog.dialog();
});
```

The php page is loaded but the data that I sent over is not showing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in essence making 2 requests to the same server script...one with data and one without.

Just use the response from the initial request to populate the dialog.

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   cache: false,
   data: {
     result: JSON.stringify(info)
   },
   url: "/best/Pages/DailyShiftReport/PageSection/IrrecoverableFilmScrap.php"
 }).done(function(response) {
   var my_dialog = $('#test_dialog_org').html(response);
   my_dialog.dialog();
 });
```

Comment: Dude your a lifesaver thx.  May God grant you many blessings!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    data: info,
    url: url
}).done(function(){
    var my_dialog =  $('#test_dialog_org').load(url);
    my_dialog.dialog();
});
```

only use `JSON.stringify()` if you're using `POST` to send JSON to an endpoint. because you're using `GET` the data object is going to be serialized onto the end of the URL, which accepts a javascript object and will turn it into key/value pairs. `JSON.stringify()` prepares JSON to be sent via XHR and, as the name suggests, returns a javascript string that you'd need to read with `JSON.parse()` method to get it back to an object.